# Obtain lowest sum from matrix, picking one value per row and column

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Essentially I have a matrix of floats ranging from 0-1, and I need to find the combination of values with the lowest sum. The kicker is that once a value is selected, no other values from that row or column may be used. All the columns must be used.

In the case the matrix's width is greater than height, it will be padded with 1's to make the matrix square. In the case the height is greater than width, simply not all the rows will be used, but all of the columns must ALWAYS be used.

I have looked into binary trees and Dijkstra's algorithm for this task, but both seem to get far too complex with larger matrices. Ideally I'm looking for an algorithm or implementation which will provide a very good guess in a relatively short amount of time. Anything optimized for c++ would be great!

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried a variety of things, from just simply scanning through each column and finding the best available fit left to some more "intelligent" solutions that use filtering before matching. I attempted to build a solution using Dijkstra but it became apparent pretty quickly that this would be far too expensive once the matrix grew above 10x10.

Comment: The only part I have that I can for sure use is a filter which pulls out any values which are the min for their row and column, since of course there isn't any better option besides those

Comment: Use a bit set or Boolean vector to indicate which columns have been processed.  Use a loop to process each row.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the suggestion. I did try that and it works fairly well, but it can cause trouble since I'm not sure how to prioritize the search. Sometimes a column is much better off taking the 2nd or 3rd lowest value so to save that row for another column which needs it more. That is why I considered Dijkstra to get the shortest cost "path", but unfortunately that solution gets far too expensive.

Comment: Please change the title of the question, to achieve minimum sum by picking one value per row/column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit's suggestion to change the title actually led me to finding the solution. It is an "Assignment Problem" and the solution is to use the Hungarian algorithm. I knew there had to be something out there already, I just wasn't sure how to phrase it to find the answer until now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Greedy Approach should work here for the good guess/optimized part.

1. Put all the elements in an array as a tuple `< value, row, column >`
2. Sort the list with `<value>` parameter of the tuple.
3. Greedily pick the elements from beginning, and keep track of the used column/row with either using bitset or boolean matrix as suggested @Thomas Mathews.

The total Complexity will be `NMlog(NM)` where N is the number of rows, and M no. of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Dijkstra algorithm for the shortest path, assuming you are constructing a tree.  In the root node you select a length of `0`, and for each node you select the next accesible element that gives you the shortest path from the root node, and store that length (from the root) in the node.  You'll add at each iteration, for all the leaves, the arc that makes *the total length* lesser, and will continue until you get a `N` nodes path (or a bitmask of `0`, see below).  The first branch of `N` nodes from the root will be the shortest path.  At each node, you can store a bitmap of the already visited nodes (or you can determine it, looking at the parents) as the possible nodes from it are the unvisited ones only.  Or you can have a bitmap of the non-visited ones.  This will make the search easier, as you'll stop as soon as no bits are on in the mask.

You have not shown any code or intent to solve the problem, so I'll do that same thing (it seems to be some kind of homework, and you seem not have work on it at all by now)  This is an academic problem, already shown in many programming courses in relation with Simplex and operations investigation, in object/resource assignment, so there must be plenty literature about it.